# arcmap network analyst iteration over multiple files using model builder

Tags: networking, model, builder, arcmap

I have 10+ files that I want to add to ArcMap then do some spatial analysis in an automated fashion. The files are in csv format which are located in one folder and named in order as "TTS11_path_points_1" to "TTS11_path_points_13". The steps are as follows:

1. Make XY event layer
2. Export the XY table to a point shapefile using the feature class to feature class tool
3. Project the shapefiles
4. Snap the points to another line shapfile
5. Make a Route layer - network analyst
6. Add locations to stops using the output of step 4
7. Solve to get routes between points based on a RouteName field

I tried to attach a snapshot of the model builder to show the steps visually but I don't have enough points to do so.

I have two problems:

1. How do I iterate this procedure over the number of files that I have?
2. How to make sure that every time the output has a different name so it doesn't overwrite the one form the previous iteration?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you're satisfied with the way the model works on a single input CSV, you can [batch](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000w000000) the operation 10+ times, manually adjusting the input/output files. This easily addresses your second problem, since you're controlling the output name.
2. You can use [an iterator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00400000001n000000) in your ModelBuilder model -- specifically, [Iterate Files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Iterate_Files/00400000000v000000/). The iterator would be the first input to the model, and has two outputs: `File` (which you link to other tools), and `Name`. The latter is a variable which you can use in other tools to control their output -- [for example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Examples_of_using_iterators_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001n000000/), you can set the final output to `C:\temp\out%Name%` instead of just `C:\temp\output`. This can be a little trickier, but once it's in place it tends to work well.

For future reference, [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com) is likely to get you a faster response.